# why my VisualWebPart, components(Chart, ListView, etc)ID changed for no reason after deployed and imported to a Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint, gridview, web-parts

My Visual Web Part contains a Gridview with ID GV_Test

After Deploy and Import to a sharepoint webpart page.

On my SP page, its id change to "ctl00_m_g_xxxxxxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxxxxxx_ctl00_GV_Test" for not reason.

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a post](http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,78dde6ae-213c-4f8c-8f9c-3e82bd67807e.aspx) that describes how the ID for webpart controls are generated on a SharePoint page.

Comment: By the way - the way the ID's are generated is defined by ASP.NET, not SharePoint as such.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by override `ClientID` and `UniqueID` methods.

both return `this.ID`

```
protected override string UniqueID { get {return this.ID; } }
protected override string ClientID { get {return this.ID; } }
```